# What kind of corn did Ray grow?

Tags: field-of-dreams

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_Dreams)

> Ray Kinsella is a novice Iowa farmer who lives with his wife Annie and daughter Karin. In the opening narration, Ray explains how he had a troubled relationship with his father, John Kinsella, who had been a devoted baseball fan. While walking through his **cornfield** one evening, Ray hears a voice whispering, "If you build it, he will come." Ray continues hearing the voice before finally seeing a vision of a baseball diamond in his field. Annie is skeptical of his vision, but she allows Ray to **plow the corn** under in order to build a baseball field.
>
> ...
>
> Ray's brother-in-law, Mark, cannot see the baseball players and warns Ray that he will go bankrupt unless he **replants his crops**. While in the field, Ray hears the voice again, this time urging him to "ease his pain."

### Is it ever mentioned what kind of corn Ray grows?

The [largest baseball field](http://www.businessinsider.com/chart-major-league-baseball-ballpark-sizes-2014-3) is less than 3 acres... while the average size of a farm closer to 400 acres and there a [five different types of corn](http://wholegrainscouncil.org/whole-grains-101/types-of-corn). Even if we consider rotation farming practices, re-purposing three acres would not be enough to cause the farm to go bankrupt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the movie doesn't say explicitly, it is doubtlessly *field corn* meaning that it is one of flint, dent, flour, or waxy corn.  We can rule out sweet corn (the type we eat) by two facts: first, only about [1% of the corn grown in Iowa (~3,400 acres) is sweet corn](https://www.iowacorn.org/resources/faqs/). That by itself suggests that Ray wasn't growing sweet corn.  In fact, it appears from the images I have seen that only one kind of corn is being grown so it isn't a matter of "maybe he was growing a little sweet corn and that's what he plowed under."

In addition, sweet corn has leaves that are [smaller than field corn, and not as tall](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/corn-identification-105152.html).  Popcorn and ornamental corn is even smaller.  A Google image search for "Field of Dreams corn" shows the corn in question is clearly taller than the players coming out of the field, and has large, broad leaves.

Answer (score 2):

From the [IMDB Trivia page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097351/trivia) (last entry):

> When Ray's brother-in-law yells at him, "Ray, do you know how much
>   this land is worth?" and he responds, "Yeah,twenty-two hundred bucks
>   an acre," the exchange is supposed to connote that the baseball field
>   represents a large, intolerable financial loss. Actually, a baseball
>   field is about two acres in size, which even if it had generous
>   proportions, meant that Ray was losing no more than $5,000 from
>   maintaining his "Field of Dreams".

So, no it's never mentioned what kind of corn he grew, but it's clear that the assumption his "Field of Dreams" was responsible for a hefty loss was a false one.